# How can I specify a browser that GWT tests should be run on?

Tags: firefox, gwt, html, canvas, testing

I am writing a GWT project that uses HTML5 canvas.

To test application I use GWTTestCase.

For firefox some functions are supported since gecko 1.9. 
While testing, firefox 3.0.1 is being used and errors occur.

How can I set up GWT tests to be launched on firefox 3.6?

(in Eclipse using GWT plugin or using build.xml for ant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MeasureText wasn't there until gecko 1.9.1.

The workaround is to run tests with runStyle=Manual:1 
This gives me link that I can paste into the browser that I want tests to be run in.

```
-Dgwt.args="-runStyle Manual:1"
```